# cudNN PoolForward Launch Failed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using DeepLabCut and I wanted to accelerate the process using my GPU. I downloaded and installed the necessary GPU drivers, cudNN, and cuda, as well as pip installing TensorFlow. The following exception raised when starting training

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Internal: cudnn PoolForward launch failed
         [[{{node resnet_v1_50/pool1/MaxPool}}]]
         [[GroupCrossDeviceControlEdges_0/huber_loss/num_present/broadcast_weights/assert_broadcastable/AssertGuard/Assert/data_7/_602]]
  (1) Internal: cudnn PoolForward launch failed
         [[{{node resnet_v1_50/pool1/MaxPool}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

Anyone know what this is? Playing around with cuda, cudNN, or tf versions didn't really help, and I'm not too sure what's causing the errors.

Thank you.